# Does any user have right to ask reason of changing accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

I was just concerned whether any user can ask reason for changing accepted answer or not. Nobody change accepted answer until finding better answer. Then why someone points on someone about their decision.

Comment: yes anyone can always ask but you mustn't answer them just like any question.

Comment: Choose what answer works for you or the one used, If unclear don't accept one, use a upvote. If you tried something different add your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

> I was just concerned whether any user can ask reason for changing accepted answer or not.

I did it recently. I saw a -15 in my votes on a topic. 3 reasons got me leaving a comment to why:

- The topic was 2 months old and had no changes to it. So that was something I considered weird. So why was it acceptable for 2 months?!
- I wanted to know if I messed something up and could improve my answer.
- From my perspective my answer was better (more universal) than the newly accepted one.

So yes, I think it should be possible to ask someone to motivate it. But the OP of course does not need to respond ;)

Comment: Thanks for making me clear. @Braiam I apologize for taking it other way. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are talking about this one: [Which distribution to choose while downloading Skype from its official site for Ubuntu 13.10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/373098/169736)

**I** asked "why you changed your accepted answer?" because you did **twice**. One to change from Radu's answer to mine, and another to change from mine to Radu's. Then I saw that you commented Radu's answer to get help with [Enable both: two finger scrolling and edge scrolling permanently](https://askubuntu.com/q/372988/169736) . Is odd that when someone change accepted answers so frequent one gets to wonder "why", "what is this user doing", "did any of them didn't do the work", "why not comment", **"what answer was really the one that solved OP's problem"**.

The timeline of the question: https://askubuntu.com/posts/373098/timeline

[image]

Comment: There is nothing personal this is my query only and ya, it's true. I am talking about that only. I was confused which to choose accepted answer. First, I tried considering both answer as accepted answer then later I came to know that only answer can be considered accepted. So, I switched back to previous answer. That's all. Hope I make you clear.

And regarding issue why not comment.
I have no problem you or anyone commenting. But, commenting on someone personal decision, I find little .. you know. 
 Truly, I appreciate you for proving answer to my question with screenshot.